# CakePHP ajax with Js Helper loads the page rather than the template for success, why?

Tags: ajax, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to make a form submit through ajax and the JsHelper from CakePHP 1.3

I try to make a call to `/eng/feedbacks/submit_feedback` but instead in the console, i see a post to `http://lang/eng/pa/homepage` instead. The result returned is another instance of that page, rather than anything else.

This seems to be irrelevant to whether such `submit_feedback` exists or not. I have started that action with `die("test");` and it doesn't change anything.

why is that, what is going on?

the form is in my layout (as i want it to be in my footer). Runs when the url is `/eng/pa/homepage`

Form code:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Feedback', array('url'=>array( 'controller'=>'feedbacks', 'action'=>'submit_feedback')));
echo $this->Form->input('Feedback.content', array('label'=>false, 'type'=>'textarea'));
echo $this->Js->submit('Save', array('class'=>'button blue',
                            'before'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeIn'),
                            'success'=>$this->Js->Get('#sending')->effect('fadeOut'),
                            'update'=>'#success'
                        ));
echo $this->Form->end();?>
<div id="success">xx</div>
```

In that #success DIV i get a related full page, rather than what I have defined in the controller action

Controller method:

```
function submit_feedback(){
    if(!empty($this->data)){
        $this->Feedback->set($this->data);
        if($this->Feedback->validates()){
            if($this->Feedback->save($this->data)){
                // AJAX
                if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
                    $this->render('/feedbacks/success', 'ajax');
                }else{
                    die('not ajax');
                    }

            }
            }
        }
}
```

And the success template is:

```
<p style="background: lightgreen">Purple cow!</p>
```

What am i doing wrong?

NOTE: If I run the same form from the `/eng/feedbacks/submit_feedback` page, It works exactly as it should through ajax, and my database gets updated, i get the necessary 'success' template loaded and all is shiny and happy.

UPDATE: FORM SOURCE COUDE GENERATED:

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" action="/eng/feedbacks/submit_feedback" method="post" id="FeedbackReadForm">
<div style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" value="POST" name="_method">
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="FeedbackUserId" value="141" name="data[Feedback][user_id]">
<div class="input radio">
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="FeedbackType_" name="data[Feedback][type]">
    <input type="radio" value="suggestion" id="FeedbackTypeSuggestion" name="data[Feedback][type]">
    <label for="FeedbackTypeSuggestion">Suggestion</label>
    <input type="radio" value="problem" id="FeedbackTypeProblem" name="data[Feedback][type]">
    <label for="FeedbackTypeProblem">Poblem</label>
    <input type="radio" value="opinion" id="FeedbackTypeOpinion" name="data[Feedback][type]">
    <label for="FeedbackTypeOpinion">Other Opinion</label>
</div>
<div class="input textarea">
    <textarea id="FeedbackContent" rows="6" cols="30" name="data[Feedback][content]"></textarea>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 17px; margin-right: 50px;" class="right">
    <a onclick="javascript: closeFeedbackPuller(); return false;" href="#">Cancel</a>
</div>
<div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" id="submit-396027771" class="button blue">
</div>
</form>
```

UPDATE 2: JS generated:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#submit-396027771").bind("click", function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend:function (XMLHttpRequest) {
            $("#sending").fadeIn();
        }, 
        data:$("#submit-396027771").closest("form").serialize(), 
        dataType:"html", 
        success:function (data, textStatus) {
            $("#sending").fadeOut();
            $("#success").html(data);
        }, 
        type:"post", 
        url:"\/eng\/pa\/homepage"
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

I see that the url is wrong, even thought the form url was right. How can this be resolved?

Comment: JS? I dont have any extra JS...

Comment: Okay, what does your rendered source look like?

Comment: check out the NOTE I added. Also, what do you mean by rendered source? If you mean in the #success div, the HTML of the template for `/eng/pa/homepage` is rendered, which is obviously totally wrong

Comment: I want to see the source code of the web page (form) in the browser.

Comment: Sorry, didin't get what you meant. Added it

Comment: Where is the generated JavaScript?

Comment: Noooow I understand how it works, JS added

Comment: However, I don't know why the URL is the wrong one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $this->Js->submit('Save', array('class'=>'button blue',
                        'before'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeIn'),
                        'success'=>$this->Js->Get('#sending')->effect('fadeOut'),
                        'url' => '/eng/feedbacks/submit_feedback',
                        'update'=>'#success'
                    ));
```

That may fix your problem, but I am not 100% sure. It seems that the Js->submit() method accepts a lot of the Form helper methods.

Comment: Yes, that worked. But I am beginning to wonder, why would I need to use JS, instead of just writing clean straightforward manual code through jQuery...